# Nesting container within a container bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm have a little bit of trouble getting a definitive answer on containers in bootstrap.  It's clear that you should not nest a `.container` within a `.container-fluid` and visa versa, but is it ok to nest a `.container` within another `.container`?  I am trying to create a layout that has an outer div that will be full width and an inner div that will be smaller that holds content, a box within a box.  I'm not sure what the proper way to do this in bootstrap is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:**

According to v4 docs, it *can* be nested but you do not require it in most cases: [Bootstrap v4 layout doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/)

---

Yes, never nest a container inside another.

**From the Bootstrap v3 Docs:**

> **Containers**
>
> Bootstrap requires a containing element to wrap site contents and
> house our grid system. You may choose one of two containers to use in
> your projects. Note that, due to padding and more, neither container
> is nestable.

You can wrap the `.container` inside custom class `.outer-container` which has 100% width. Set a width near 75% when the screen size is reduced to show that the inner container has a smaller width.

```css
.outer-container {
  background: tomato;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  background: lightblue;
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .outer-container .container {
    width: 75%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="container">
    I am fixed
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `.outer-container` a bootstrap class that needs to be overridden or just a user defined class?

Comment: It is a user defined class.

Comment: @ManojKumar Thanks for referencing to Bootstrap Docs as it helped me a lot. I was getting undesired layouts since I had containers inside containers.

Answer (score 6):

For Bootstrap 4, containers can be nested.

> Containers
>
> Containers are the most basic layout element in Bootstrap and are
> required when using our default grid system. Choose from a responsive,
> fixed-width container (meaning its max-width changes at each
> breakpoint) or fluid-width (meaning it’s 100% wide all the time).
>
> **While containers can be nested, most layouts do not require a nested container.**

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/

Answer (score 2):

According to [Bootstrap 3 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/)

> Note that, due to padding and more, neither container is nestable.

However, in Bootstrap 3 a `navbar` has a `.container` inside it and at the same time it can all be enveloped by a bigger `.container`. So there is a `.container` within a `.container` and it is not a mistake. To verify that one may look at the page source here, in Bootstrap documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/navbar/